# Scan beacons in background on iOS and Android with Delphi

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

I have an aplication that scans Beacons on run time, but the intention is to look for the beacons in background on iOS and Android.
On android application i almost got there by using an Android service to search beacons and show notifications with TNotificationCenter. But the androuid service only starts when i open the application, i think it could be independent, is it possible to do?
On iOS Platform its not possible create service like on Android, so i dont know what to do.

Best regards

Comment: There's a demo here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/ScheduledService that makes the service start at boot. The demo also starts the app at boot, but that can be remove in the manifest template. Note that with Play Store requiring a target of API 26+, the demo may need updating, and in fact should probably use either a JobIntentService (which Delphi is yet to support) or IntentService (which currently does not work with Delphi), or maybe even a BroadcastReceiver for the beacon events. Yet another thing to add to my to-do list

Comment: iOS and Android are different. Dave Nottage is correct, in Android you can create a Service that boots with the phone but it will only do that after the app has been started at least once. iOS supports background execution mode.

Comment: The demo is very helpfull. I can start a service on boot, but how can i do it on iOS?
Is there a example code with any task on iOS background?